# Counting a number of purchases with the same data values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have the following table

How can I write an SQL statement to find out how many purchases there has been for which there are at least 1000 other purchases with the same ServiceType, PaymentType and GST values?

I know I need to use a count aggregate and I think the query should start like this

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need count instead of sum. Or sum the amount if you need to the total amount.

```
SELECT COUNT(PurchaseNo)
FROM PURCHASE
GROUP BY ServiceType, PaymentType, GST
HAVING COUNT(PurchaseNo) >= 1000
```

Comment: why is`PaymentType`  double in `GROUP BY ServiceType, PaymentType, PaymentType`?

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm a tad embarrassed I thought that was a lot harder than it actually was! Will accept soon

Comment: @priti thx for pointing that out, just a copy error should have been GST

Answer (score 3):

```
select count(*) 
from PURCHASE
group by ServiceType, PaymentType, GST
having count(*) >= 1000
```

Comment: I think this goes wrong, since it doesn't know cnt in the having clause? Not sure.

Comment: +1 but @NLwino is correct: Oracle doesn't like the alias in the `having` clause. If you change it to `having count(*) >= 1000` it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
select COUNT(*),ServiceType, PaymentType, GST 
FROM PURCHASE
having count(*) > 1000
group by ServiceType, PaymentType, GST;
```

Comment: Just needed the purchases, but thank you, still jogged my memory, cant believe I didn't think of it!